# Books For Learning C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to learn C# and the .Net Framework as well.

I have no idea on the Microsoft .Net and C# framework but I once programmed on their Microsoft Visual Basic 6 with experience on making COM Components (OCX and DLL).

I have an experience programming on java and have fair knowledge of Object Oriented Technology.  But I am currently confused on the number of books currently written for C#.

I want a book that will not explain me the for loop or iterative looping on one chapter but more on the language itself.  I've heard that C# is a close cousin of Java so I think I just want to know the syntax.

Since I dont know C# and .Net framework< i would like a book that could focus on them.

Currently, as I have viewed from the net.
I have this list of books:

- Head First C#
- Illustrated C#
- MS C# 2008 Step By STep
- Illustrated C#
- C# 3.0 in a Nutshell
- Wrox Beginning C# 2008
- C# in Depth

From the review in amazon, they all look good but I dont know which one of them or that is not in the list that I have would suit me.

I definitely want to learn C# so hopefully someone can help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform, Fourth Edition](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590598849) is my favorite. It takes you from the CLR basics all the way to the advanced 3.5 topics.

You can read the first few chapters now to get a good grip on the basics and then go on with the more advanced chapters when you feel ready for it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a fan of the [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632), by Jeffrey Richter, a man very, very wise in C#-fu.

Also, check out our very own [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s [C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988363).

Both are great reads.

Comment: CLR via C# is a very advanced book

Comment: As I understood it, the OP is looking for a book to get him the nuts and bolts of C# and .NET, not an intro to programming book. CLR via C# does just that, which is why I recommended it.

Comment: I'm reading c# in Depth now.  Been very useful so far...

Comment: I do pretty much assume that people know C# 1 syntax though... if the OP gets C# in Depth, he'll probably want to read a quick tutorial for C# 1 as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Effective C#](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-C-Specific-Ways-Improve/dp/0321245660/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1244623497&sr=8-2) and [More Effective C#](http://www.amazon.co.uk/More-Effective-Specific-Software-Development/dp/0321485890/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1244623497&sr=8-1) by Bill Wagner are worth a read.

Or [Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321245660) and [More Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321485890) if you're in the States.

Answer (score 2):

[C# 3.0 in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527578) has really helped me understand C# in depth; I recommend it for anyone.

Although I wouldn't say it's really a beginner's book per ce.

[alt text http://www.ixsoft.de/Web_store/Images/256/9780596527570.jpg](http://www.ixsoft.de/Web_store/Images/256/9780596527570.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Wrox C# 2008 is excellent.

Comment: Now if only they'd fix the title ;-p

Answer (score 1):

I always loved video tutorials, it just makes you use more senses than you use when reading, which makes you focus more.
you can refer to

http://channel9.msdn.com

http://www.dnrtv.com

http://windowsclient.com

http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos.aspx

http://www.asp.net/learn/

Answer (score 1):

I learned with "Visual C# 2008 Step by Step" by John Sharp. (That's gotta be a pen name, right?) I found it effective.

Answer (score 0):

C# in depth is a very good read and probably well worth reading even if you know C# a little.

There are lots of little gems of information that you pick up.

Comment: Yes but which edition?